# Android: How to change more than just Text, Text Color and image resource?

Tags: android, image, text, android-widget

At the moment I am using RemoteViews to update my Widget. The problem is - it only allows me to change the color of the text and the text itself. updateViews.setTextViewText() and updateViews.setTextViewColor(). It's also very limited with images

How would I, for example change tint of an image in a widget dynamically. So, for example change the tint of an image depending on the weather etc.

Thanks

shadrxninga

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can  try apply tint by semi-transparent overlay in your layout -  via background setting.
App-Widgets changes vie remote views  are very limited due to security considerations -   they are effectively executed by launcher, so API is really paranoid to prevent everything that may be descructive.

Comment: So, it's impossible to let the user pick any color they want for the widget background (In the configuration), then apply a tint over the image in the widget to do so

Comment: It could be possible.  Try to place image view, containing transparent image over area you like to tint.   Then try to set background of overlay image view to semi-transparent tint.   It may work